# Whois Parser error for ORG/NET URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whois, whois-ruby

I have checking the whois information for .org/.net/.ae sites. While parsing it was giving error.

This is my code part:

```
record = Whois.whois(url)
date = record.created_on
```

Its giving the following error

```
Whois::ParserError: Unexpected token: Access to .ORG
```

What is the issue here. Its working for .com URLs.

Comment: Would you show your `url`, please.

Comment: What whois gem or library are you using?  Could you provide the name of the gem and a link to the documentation?  Also, the .ORG whois server has a very severe rate limit, so you should just try typing `whois abc.org` at a command prompt to see if your computer is getting rate limited by the whois server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has been fixed in [this pull-request](https://github.com/weppos/whois/pull/300) and I've released a new version today. Make sure to use the v3.4.4.